# How to extend template from another module?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a project with the following structure:

```
project    
    project
        static/
        templates
            project
                base.html
        __init__.py
        .....
    events
        static/
        templates
            events
                events.html
        __init__.py
        models.py
        .....
```

### **The problem**

I want to extend `base.html` in `events.html`

I tried with:

```
{% extends "project:project/base.html" %}
```

But get the following **error**:

```
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    project:project/base.html
```

Also tried with:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

But the same **error** is returned:

```
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    base.html
```

**In `INSTALLED_APPS` I have:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'events',
    'project',
)
```

**`TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `BASE_DIR`:**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

**In `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` I have:**

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

)
```

Comment: Please show your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the settings there. Thanks. Also, what is `BASE_DIR`?

Comment: Work with {% extends "project/base.html" %}

Comment: It looks like you need the same base template at 2 different places, so why not just extract it to the base template directory and inherit at both the places from there? This way, code is clean, and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TEMPLATE_DIR` is set to `project/templates`, not `project/templates/project`.

Since there is no `base.html` in `project/templates`, Django returns an error.

You could either move `base.html` up to `project/templates`, or reference it by writing :

```
{% extends "project/base.html" %}
```